# -bash: cd: app: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, terminal

I simply changed the name in finder and now when I use a command in terminal, this is the error I keep receiving. I've tried to look at all the other cases of the same error but they all pertain to different solutions that don't work. The path is clearly correct because when I try to cd into the directory, I'm already in the directory it is contained in.

```
Johns-MacBook-Air:SongAnalysisSentiment johnanukem$ cd app
-bash: cd: app: No such file or directory
Johns-MacBook-Air:SongAnalysisSentiment johnanukem$ ls
README          app             sentiments.csv      songdictionary.py
Johns-MacBook-Air:SongAnalysisSentiment johnanukem$ ls -lah
total 776
drwxr-xr-x   8 johnanukem  staff   272B Nov 14 02:38 .
drwx------+ 39 johnanukem  staff   1.3K Nov 14 02:38 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 johnanukem  staff   6.0K Nov 14 01:39 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x  16 johnanukem  staff   544B Nov 14 02:43 .git
-rw-r--r--   1 johnanukem  staff    35B Nov 14 01:38 README
drwxr-xr-x   8 johnanukem  staff   272B Nov 14 02:38 app 
-rw-r--r--   1 johnanukem  staff   370K Nov 14 01:49 sentiments.csv
-rw-r--r--   1 johnanukem  staff   1.3K Nov 14 02:29 songdictionary.py
```

Comment: can you post the output of `ls -lah`

Comment: Perhaps a screenshot is best, you van edit your question and add it - maybe before taking the screenshot, you could also try to cd into the app directory, so we can see ourselves what is happening

Comment: Please run `ls -lah` not just `ls`. And update  your question with the output.

Comment: @asimovwasright: Sigh, please don't ask for a screenshot! Textual output should be added to the question.

Comment: @Biffen are you guessing it's a broken symbolic link ? :) `ls -l` should have showed it, no?

Comment: Is `cd .git` working ?

Comment: yes but that doesn't allow me into the app directory.

Comment: @JohnAnukem Could you post the output of `file app`?

Comment: Johns-MacBook-Air:SongAnalysisSentiment johnanukem$ ls
        README   app    sentiments.csv         songdictionary.py
        Johns-MacBook-Air:SongAnalysisSentiment johnanukem$ file app
        app: cannot open `app' (No such file or directory)
        Johns-MacBook-Air:SongAnalysisSentiment johnanukem$

Comment: type cd ap[Press Tab] to autocomplete, may be its an space after app

Comment: @JohnAnukem `file app*` then?

Comment: There was a space after. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

type `cd ap` and then [Press Tab] to autocomplete, may be there is some spaces after app

Answer (score 0):

On **MacOS** with the default Bash

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

`cd app` raises the error

```
-bash: cd: app: No such file or directory
```

due to a bug of the super old Bash version installed with MacOS.

The workaround is to prefix the directory with `./` in this way

```
cd ./app
```

and it will work.

The alternative is to install a modern and better Bash version using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

```
brew install bash
```